# Let $\alpha$ be a limit ordinal. $f: \alpha \to \beta $ be strictly increase cofinal map. then $cf(\alpha) = cf(\beta)$.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

Let $\alpha$ be a limit ordinal.  $f: \alpha \to \beta $ be strictly increase cofinal map.then $cf(\alpha) = cf(\beta)$.

refer to proof in the Kenneth Kunen's book. It's easy to show that $cf(\alpha) \leq cf(\beta)$ by composing a function from $cf(\alpha) \to \alpha$ with $f$.

To show that $cf(\beta) \leq cf(\alpha)$.(refer to the book). Let $g: cf(\beta) \to \beta$ be a cofinal map and consider a function $h:cf(\beta) \to \alpha$. define by $h(\xi) = \eta$. $\eta$ is least element such that $f(\eta) > g(\xi)$. How to show that $h:cf(\beta) \to \alpha$ is cofinal?

Here what I'm trying to proof:

Let $x \in \alpha$. We need to show that there is $\zeta \in cf(\beta)$ with $h(\zeta) \geq x$. And then I got stuck. How to do then?

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For each $\xi\in\operatorname{cf}(\beta)$ we have $(f\circ h)(\xi)>g(\xi)$, so $f\circ h$ is cofinal in $\beta$. Show that if $h$ were not cofinal in $\alpha$, then $f\circ h$ could not be cofinal in $\beta$.

Comment: Suppose that $h$ is not cofinal in $\alpha$. Then there is $x$ such that $x > h(\zeta)$ for all $\zeta \in cf(\beta)$. then $f(x) \in \beta > f \circ h(\zeta)$ for all $\zeta \in cf(\beta)$. Contradict the cofinality of $f \circ h$. Can I conclude that?

Comment: @Arikakakaya: Yes; the crucial point here is that $f$ is strictly increasing.

Comment: @Arikakakaya: The result is uninteresting when $\alpha$ is not a limit ordinal: in that case $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are both successor ordinals, and $\alpha\le\beta$, but that says nothing interesting about them. In general cofinality is of interest only for limit ordinals.

Comment: It's trivial in case $\alpha$ is a successor , $s(\theta)$,  $cf(\alpha) = 1$ since consider $f(0) = \theta$.$f$ is cofinal in $\alpha$.  And by $cf(\beta) \leq cf(\alpha) =1$. then $cf(\beta) =1=cf(\alpha)$.

Comment: @Arikakakaya: Yes: trivial and fundamentally uninteresting. Cofinality is generally of interest only for limit ordinals, since it tells you nothing about successor ordinals.